# QGIS Authentication

Tags: qgis, authentication

I have been doing some reading regarding QGIS authentication.  Like most of the threads I have read, I am getting a barrage of authentication requests when someone opens someone else's QGIS project file.  We are connecting to a PostGIS instance on Azure, and all tables are in the same database.
Do we all have use the same Master Password in our QGIS client to avoid this?  That seems a little silly as what is the point of having it then?
A little confused as to how to avoid this.  Anyone........?
m